# How to save python pandas column de-duped to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, duplicates, export-to-csv

Working with a simple dataframe df:

```
ID | other columns
123
123
343
345
234
234
```

I want to save the first column to a csv but de-duped.

```
df['ID'].to_csv('file.csv')
```

How can I de-dupe before the save? Thank You

Comment: `df['ID'].drop_duplicates().to_csv('file.csv')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) if `ID` is column:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).to_csv('file.csv')
```

If `ID` is index need [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()].to_csv('file.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `unique elements` or `drop_duplicates` to get unique list of ID's

```
df['ID'].unique().to_csv('file.csv')
```